# Margin in titlebar for Window Icon on Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a form, I added a Icon in the design.

I would like to put margin on the icon in the title bar, its too much to the left, is this possible?

Comment: The title bar is part of the [non-client area](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c0785ef8-aaa0-4609-8fe1-7fbdf574c4cc/what-is-meaning-of-windows-client-area-on-link?forum=vcgeneral), meaning that you cannot (easily) customize it. You would have to [roll your own window style](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42223/Easy-Customize-Title-Bar) or try to achieve what you want using Winapi functions.

Comment: Is it your own icon?  If so then just add some space to the left in the icon

Comment: @LordWilmore Yes I was thinking of that too, but then it will be affected in the taskbar as well

Comment: @KickanG very good point